# How to change the button position when pressed in tkinter python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

please tell me how to change the position of the button in tkinter. I predicted that it could be done by button`['padx' = 4]`, but it doesn't work. Do you know how to do it?

```
from tkinter import ttk
import random

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('512x512')

def click():
    pass


button = ttk.Button(
    text="No",
    command=click
).pack(padx=5, pady=15)



window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I instead assigned 2 variables to random integers, and then updated the position of the button with those variables. If you want the random position to be a wider area increase the number "100" in "random_int".

```
from tkinter import *
import random

window = Tk()
window.geometry('512x512')

x = 5
y = 15


def click():
  random_int = random.randint(0, 100)
  x = (random_int)
  random_int = random.randint(0, 100)
  y = (random_int)
  button.place(x=x, y=y)


button = Button(text="No", command=click)

button.pack(padx=5, pady=15)

window.mainloop()
```